# QGIS / Python - Select features until the cumulative sum target is reached

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-attribute, qgis-python-console

I have a polygon feature of municipalities with the value of production of some good in the attribute table field `production`. I need to know which are the municipalities with the lowest production that add a value lower than `X` (let's say <=200). Consider the sample attribute table below with ascending order:

```
mun production
a   1
b   15
c   19
d   26
e   76
f   80
g   95
h   100
```

Now I need to select those from the top to the bottom which the cumulative sum <=200

This is how far I got:

```py
# get layer
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

# establishing the orderby for the attribute table
clause = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause('production', ascending=True)
orderby = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([clause])
request.setOrderBy(orderby)

# get the attribute table ordered
features = layer.getFeatures(request)

# check if the atribute table is ordered
for ft in features:
    attrs = ft.attributes()
    print(attrs[1]) # ok, table sorted!
```

Now I need to select those which sum up <=200. I know I need a `while` statement. But can't figure out how to make it work. No working attempt until now.

Another simplest approach I can't realize how to implement would be to calculate the cumulative sum of `production` in the sorted attribute table and then "manually" use the `Select features by expression` tool. But I really don't know how to calculate the cmulative sum in a sorted attribute table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. Replace `myLayer` with your layer name, and feel free to add other fields.

It creates a window function which incrementally sums the `production` values. It does it for every row in the table. Then, the outer query selects everything from the inner query for all rows having a cumulative sum below the desired threshold.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT mun, production, 
         sum(production) OVER (order by production) as cumul 
  FROM myLayer) c
WHERE c.cumul <= 200;
```

If you want to keep the geometry, you can add the field `geometry`

```sql
...
SELECT mun, production, geometry,
       sum(production) OVER (order by production) as cumul
```

or even use `*` to keep all current fields

```sql
...
SELECT *,
       sum(production) OVER (order by production) as cumul
```

Comment: That's great, it works. But it doesn't retrieve the grometries, right? Is there a way to retrieve the geometries of the features?

Comment: Great!! Works just as expected!! Thanks a lot! Do you mind adding it to your answer?

Comment: @Jecogeo Awesome, see edits